# Child component not listening to the changes in the parent form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

From a parent component, I am passing the form array to the child component in this way.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <hello [myForm]="myForm"></hello>
</form>
```

In the parent component **.ts** I have fetched the data from API and bind the result to the form array.

Form array is defined as:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  frequency: [2, Validators.required],
  memberid: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

In the **ngOnInit()** i have called the the function callApi():

```
async callApi() {

    const fTitle = this.myForm.controls.memberid as FormArray;
    const response = await fetch(this.url);
    const json = await response.json();
    
    let arr = [];
    json.map((item) => arr.push(item.id));
    arr.forEach((item) => fTitle.push(this.fb.control(item)));
    console.log(this.myForm.value);

}

ngOnInit(){
    this.callApi();
}
```

In the child component, I am trying to filter the `memberList` with an memberid that is passed in the form group.

```
export class HelloComponent {
  public memberScheduleNotifications = [];
  public memberList = [
    { id: 2, name: 'a' },
    { id: 1, name: 'b' },
    { id: 3, name: 'c' },
    { id: 4, name: 'd' },
  ];
  @Input() myForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.memberFilter();
  }

  memberFilter() {
    const member = this.myForm.controls.memberid as FormArray;
    this.memberScheduleNotifications = member.value || [];
    this.memberList = this.memberList.map((x) =>
      this.memberScheduleNotifications.find((y) => y == x.id)
        ? { ...x, selected: true }
        : { ...x }
    );
  }
}
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <div class="form-group">
      <p>child component</p>
      <pre> {{memberList | json}}</pre>
  </div>      
     `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
```

Here the member list is not filtered with the member id passed from the parent component. The view is displayed without the filter being applied.

The child component not listening to the changes in the parent form array, which is updated through the API call.

What I am doing wrong here?

[Working demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yinrf2)

Answer (score 1):

Your child component is not detecting the changes because you are pushing the memberlist into the FormArray, so for Angular is like you are not updating the reference you are sending to the child component.

To Angular detect the change in your child component you can:

- Reassign the form, to detect a change in the input and refresh the component.
- Forcing it with [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#!#run-anchor) or [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Answer (score 0):

Because you using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, Angular is not running running change detection cycle, thus the latest data is not appearing in your `app.component.html` or in child component.

I was not able to make `ChangeDetectionRef` work with `aync/await`, but I was curious if I can find a workaround to provide you a workable solution. I made it work with Angular's 'HttpClient'. I also added an `*ngIf` check, so that child component doesn't load until data has been fetched from API. I also had to use `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit` in child component, to get the latest `myForm` value from parent.

Hope this helps you to get on right track.

[Stackbliz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxcz4x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

- removed use of `ChangeDetectionRef` and `OnChanges`, after OP mentioned use of `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` not necessary.

app.component.html:

```
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: Todo[]) => {
      this.arrHttp = [];
      const fTitle = this.myForm.controls.memberid as FormArray;
      data.map((item) => this.arrHttp.push(item.id));
      this.arrHttp.forEach((item) => fTitle.push(this.fb.control(item)));
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
```

app.component.html:

```
<hello *ngIf="arrHttp && arrHttp.length" [myForm]="myForm"></hello>
```

hello.component.ts:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.myForm && changes.myForm.currentValue) {
      this.myForm = changes.myForm.currentValue;
      this.memberFilter();
    }
  }

  memberFilter() {
    const member = this.myForm.controls.memberid as FormArray;
    this.memberScheduleNotifications = member.value || [];
    this.memberList = this.memberList.map((x) =>
      this.memberScheduleNotifications.find((y) => y == x.id)
        ? { ...x, selected: true }
        : { ...x }
    );
  }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is not necessary here, i have added to test whether it is working or not but the result was same

Comment: and what made your code work? is it if the implementation of change detection or using *ngIf?

Comment: It's the use of *ngIf. I have removed the use of cdr in stackblitz, since you mentioned it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this little hack in hello.component.html:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="myForm.valueChanges | async"></ng-container>
```

This async pipe will trigger change detection